# Is the usage "... is/are hurting" from a victim's perspective grammatically correct?

Tags: american-english, gerunds

I recall listening to a statement by Obama one or two years ago (also after a shooting incident, most likely) where he remarked something like "... our people are hurting". Since he was referring to the victims and their families, the context was pretty clear. Nonetheless, I somehow cringed at the usage and tried to find if it was grammatically correct. I couldn't and forgot about it... today, while reading this [BBC news article](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-33159820), I saw another person (an American, most likely) quoting "Some people are hurting".

That leads me to believe this might be just an American thing but it would be nice to know if that's not the case and/or if the usage is grammatically correct?

Comment: Are you concerned about the intransitive usage, the continuous tense, or both? Have you consulted dictionaries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a recognized world-wide English usage of the verb *[hurt](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hurt?q=hurting)*:

> verb (past and past participle hurt)
>
> 1.3 [NO OBJECT] (Of a person) feel distress:
>   *he was hurting badly, but he smiled through his tears*
>
> <sub>ODO</sub>

Comment: And this is general reference.